# Crash on startup. error while loading shared libraries

Tags: libraries, shared-library

newbie here.

While I was trying to fix something, I followed a bad advice and removed protobuf library files from /usr/local/lib. Now cinnamon crashes at startup saying:

error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf-lite.so.9

I think I've reinstalled libprotobuf, but now in /usr/local/lib there are the following files:

libprotobuf-lite.so, libprotobuf-lite.so.12, libprotobuf.so, libprotobuf-lite.so.12.

I guess it's a different version so I somehow need to make sure that at startup, libprotobuf-lite.so.12 is called instead of .9

Using ln command, I've tried linking .so files to .so.12 files but didn't work.

Appreciate all your help.